# Create relation between models with Loopback

Tags: api, foreign-keys, loopbackjs, strongloop, endpoint

I am working with Loopback which is really great but i'm experiencing a problem and I can't find a clue to resolve it.
I have a MySql database called "library" composed of two tables: "book" and "category".

book (id, name, id_category)
category (id, name, desciption)

I want to query the two tables via one http request.For example, if i want to get the data, it outputs:

```
{
  id:..
  name:...
  id_category:...
  name_category:...
  description:...
}
```

I can't get it work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slc loopback:relation
from model: Book
relationship Type: belongs to
with model: Category
relationship name: category
foreign key: id_category

via rest 
make a GET request to /api/Books?filter[includes]=category

Comment: Please add more detail.

Comment: please enlightment me on what detail is missing?  it is the command to create a relation,  it has the necessary info on how to create the relation, what relationship to use. from which model and what model the relation is tied and which field will bind the relation.

It also show how to test the relation